# CSS is changed when logged out vs logged in?

Tags: css, wordpress, debugging

When logged in, my breadcrumbs look fine: https://prnt.sc/0qBJlpehUEyc, upon logged out here's how it looks: https://prnt.sc/9PTmycWgxvGP. I've cleared my WP Rocket and WP Engine caches and made sure CSS compiling is off to no avail.

I'm using the latest version of the Avada theme. Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

see the console to make sure what happened, maybe the issue not from css but from jquery, try to set Never cache this page on wp rocket option on page editor